# What are the effective scaling modes on OSX with a 4K display? Is an effective real estate of 2560x1440 possible?

Tags: macos, resolution, display

I have a 2015 retina macbook pro, the default scaled resolution of 1920x1080 would be too small for me. I currently have a 2560x1440 display and couldn't accept less real estate.

Under the display settings, if you select "scaled" you should be able to choose between "larger text" or "more space". If I understand correctly, all of these options should use 3840x2160 pixels to render the output (ie, the monitor wont know the difference). The default scaling option should be the equivalent of 1920x1080. I was wondering if you choose "more space" it would allow for the equivalent of 2560x1440 (but scaled so should look crisper than a 2560x1440 display).

[image]

As a bonus question, would this be comfortable on a 24" display (eg, Dell P2415Q)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bought one (the Dell P2415Q) so can offer the results...

Scaled options are:
`1504x846`, `1920x1080`, `2304x1296`, `2560x1440` and `3008x1692`

That is to say, the macbook always outputs `3840x2160`, `60Hz` as far as the monitor is concerned. It just "looks like" those resolutions in terms of real-estate.

`1920x1080` is the default, and other scaled resolutions are given with the warning that "Using a scaled resolution may affect performance".

eg.

Looks like `1920x1080`:
[image: 1080]

Looks like `3008x1692`:
[image: 1692]

Source: My MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015), running 10.10.4, 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5, Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB

Answer (score 9):

Note that if you **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+click** the "Scaled" resolution radio in the display preferences you will see many more resolution options than the default 5 (source: [Apple support article "Using 4K displays, 5K displays, and Ultra HD TVs with your Mac"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587)).

The options depend on the maximum resolution of your monitor and possibly your Mac graphic card/Mac generation etc.

### MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) + LG 27 inch 4K monitor

[image: Screenshot of the Display Settings on a MacBook Pro 2015 + LG 27 inch 4K monitor]

Full list:

- 3840 x 2160 (4K)
- 3360 x 1890
- 3200 x 1800
- 3008 x 1692
- 2560 x 1440
- 2304 x 1296
- 2048 x 1152
- 1920 x 1080 (Full HD)
- 1680 x 945
- 1600 x 900
- 1503 x 846
- 1280 x 720
- 1152 x 648

### Macbook Air (M1, 2020) + SAMSUNG 28 inch 4K monitor

(Full monitor model: U28R550UQRXEN)

[image: Screenshot of the Display Settings on a MacBook Air 2020 + Samsung 28 inch 4K monitor]

Full list, including "low resolution" modes:

- 3840 x 2160 (4K)
- 3008 x 1692
- 3008 x 1692 (low resolution)
- 2560 x 1440
- 2560 x 1440 (low resolution)
- 2304 x 1296
- 2304 x 1296 (low resolution)
- 2048 x 1152
- 2048 x 1152 (low resolution)
- 1920 x 1080 (Full HD)
- 1920 x 1080 (Full HD) (low resolution)
- 1680 x 945
- 1600 x 900
- 1600 x 900 (low resolution)
- 1504 x 846*
- 1280 x 720
- 1280 x 720 (low resolution)
- 1152 x 648

* - yes, it is 1504 vertical while above this resolution had 1503 vertical ‍♂️

**And to answer your bonus question:**

I am guessing that you use 2560x1440 on a 27-inch display now.

If so then to be comfortable you should get also 27-inch 4K monitor and use scaled resolution from the list above that will "look like" 2560x1440.

You will get the same screen real estate and the same size of everything, just sharper.

However, performance will be noticeably worse, in form of a delay after you type something and before it appears on the screen. Of course it will be in the range of milliseconds, but you will notice it.

**Update**: The delay I wrote about above was noticeable on the MacBook I had then (2015 Pro 15 inch without a dedicated GPU). With my current one, a 2018 Pro 15 inch with a dedicated GPU, the delay is not noticeable to me (but of course it's a subjective thing, you may notice it).

Comment: Does the full list apply to Apple Silicon Macs (M1+)?

Comment: I have expanded my answer with that info, @cprcrack.

Answer (score 0):

Default is (like) 2560 by 1440.
The next smaller one would be (like) 1920 by 1080.
The next larger would be 3008 by 1692, and the "More Space" would be 3840 by 2160.

Source: [macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/2155464/hands-on-improved-4k-display-support-in-os-x-10-9-3.html)

Comment: I asked the same question on Amazon and got a different set of resolutions. Perhaps the options changed in a version of OSX, or maybe the options change depending on detected screen size? http://www.amazon.co.uk/effective-scaling-macbook-2560x1440-possible/forum/Fx15ZK1R3OVZVJB/Tx1YD2P7RO35PXV/1/